# resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius

Tags: android

Anybody help to fix these errors?

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible

compileSdkVersion 27 

    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2' 

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.techware.lataxi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Here are the errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
/Users/djaafar/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/c614cbb8a9d09e1466ab2b05de7d77ce/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml

Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
/Users/djaafar/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/c614cbb8a9d09e1466ab2b05de7d77ce/res/values/values.xml
Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
/Users/djaafar/Desktop/Taxi/LaTaxi/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml

Error:(11) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

Error:(7) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

Error:(11) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

/Users/djaafar/Desktop/Taxi/LaTaxi/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml

Error:(751) resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(751) resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your compileSdkVersion to 28.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```